# Cannot convert datatype nvarchar to numeric

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameterized-query, table-valued-parameters

I import data from from an Excel file into a SQL Server database with the following query. The Excel file has all values as string types (`'` before every cells).

I get this error when I import it."Cannot convert datatype nvarchar to numeric"

If I remove the two columns SalePrice and Price2 from importing, then the import is successful.

The datatypes of my table is

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[InventoryType] AS TABLE
(
   [LocalSKU] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
   [ItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
   [QOH] [int] NULL,
   [Price] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
   [Discontinued] [bit] NULL,
   [Barcode] [varchar](25) NULL,
   [Integer2] [int] NULL,
   [Integer3] [int] NULL,
   [SalePrice] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
   [SaleOn] [bit] NULL,
   [Price2] [decimal](19, 4) NULL
)
GO
```

The query I am using is:

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand
   (@"MERGE Inventory AS target
      USING (SELECT
                LocalSKU, ItemName, QOH, Price, Discontinued, 
                Barcode, Integer2, Integer3, SalePrice, SaleOn, Price2 
             FROM @source) AS Source ON (Source.LocalSKU = target.LocalSKU)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE 
           SET ItemName = source.ItemName,
               Price = source.Price,
               Discontinued = source.Discontinued,
               Barcode = source.Barcode,
               Integer2 = source.Integer2,
               Integer3 = source.QOH,
               SalePrice = source.SalePrice,
               SaleOn = source.SaleOn,
               Price2 = source.Price2;", sqlconn);

SqlParameter param;
param = sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", dr);
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.TypeName = "dbo.InventoryType";

sqlconn.Open();
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlconn.Close();
```

Comment: That statement isn't inserting anything - it's only updating existing rows ..... also: you didn't post the actual **error** that you're getting!

Comment: @marc_s I have updated the question. Yes it is only updating.

Comment: Is the type of column `QOH` convertible into a numeric type?

Comment: @DavidRTribble  No. I have lot of dependencies. I was working on this and I found that if I remove the two columns SalePrice and Price2 , then the import is successful.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that you may have some invalid data in the given column that's throwing the error(s).  For example if you have a Numeric column and have letters or inproperly formatted numeric values, this error will be thrown.  Check for values in your cells that aren't correct first.  This includes trailing or leading spaces as well.

Comment: @TechieJoe Your are correct. Invalid Data. Thanks.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then and then you can give it a check if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that you may have some invalid data in the given column that's throwing the error(s). For example if you have a Numeric column and have letters or inproperly formatted numeric values, this error will be thrown. Check for values in your cells that aren't correct first. This includes trailing or leading spaces as well.